# What means "Reconciliation" from Argo CD

Tags: monitoring, cicd

I m looking a metric in Grafana from a official Dashboard from Argo CD, the panel its named "Reconciliation Activity" and use the following metric:

```
argocd_app_reconcile_count
```

I look for a while in internet what means "reconciliation" for Argo CD but I do not find any result.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situation like this I tend to visit the project and dig in some code. For this particular case this is the PR that the metric was introduced in - https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/1184. You can go from there and do some more research.

`argocd_app_reconcile_count` is metric related to [Argo CD Application Controller](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/server-commands/argocd-application-controller/), basically each time a [*reconcile action*](https://github.com/jessesuen/argo-cd/blob/5d9aa989f39340cf9526339d452497fb03039b4f/controller/appcontroller.go#L1176-L1258) is executed the count is incremented.

Reconcile may broadly mean: "state refresh/re-check".